# Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово «интернет» в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Подскажите, нужны ли кавычки и в целом возможно ли так построить предложение:

> Интернет это средство коммуникации. Однако  под «интернетом» можно
>   иметь ввиду сторонние программы.

Или лучше:

Можно говорить (сказать) интернет, а подразумевать

Comment: «Иметь в виду» пишется раздельно.

Comment: Потерялось тире перед *это*: интернет — это средство коммуникации.

Comment: "Интернет — это средство коммуникации" звучит как определение понятия *интернет*. Если так, то это определение неполное, а значит неверное.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая фраза крайне неграмотна в первую очередь с технической точки зрения. Понятно, что именно изначально хотел сказать автор, но получилось... так себе.
Давайте я попробую высказать то, что он имел в виду, но так, чтобы это было проще понять:

**Интернет - это телекоммуникационная сеть. Однако словом "интернет" иногда также называют программы для доступа к интернету.**

Comment: Да, у вас гораздо лучше))

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки в вашем исходном примере вполне уместны.

В первом случае слово «интернет» употребляется без кавычек в своем обычном (общепринятом) значении. Затем вы как бы ставите это значение под вопрос и исследуете другие возможные значения уже этого *термина*, и именно это подчеркивается кавычками.

> #### Слова, употребляемые в необычном, условном, ироническом значении
>
> Кавычками выделяются:
>
> 2. слова, употребленные в особом, необычном значении

[(Розенталь, § 128)](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxxiii.html#sect128)